# Как обрезать число?

Tags: php

Всем здравствуйте, скажите появилась проблема, решил вывести на странице сколько дней живёт сайт, формулу правильно построил первые две цифры соответствуют кол-ву дней жизни сайта, а потом идёт точка и много цифр, так вот скажите как оставить всё что идёт **ПЕРЕД** точкой, а точку и всё что идёт после неё удалить.

Пример как всё выглядит можете увидеть на сайте: [этом](http://wm-lider.ru/)
Внизу статистики сайта.

Comment: Ведь это верно, что качество сайта напрямую зависит от качества разработчика. На вашем сайте это очень хорошо проявляется =)

Answer (score 2):

[intval()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php) или [floor()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.floor.php)

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

а почему `date` или `datetime` (`date_diff`) не использовать?

[почитайте про date_diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Не знаю...

Comment: интересный ответ, содержательный)

ну [почитайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php)